# JQuery continue chain after getting the callback

Tags: jquery, callback, chaining

I am developing a jquery plugin that runs a series of functions. The functions will be autoplayed or shall be run upon human intervention.

Is it possible to do something like this?

for example :

```
$('selector').bgChange({name:'you',callback).bgmChange() //Wait for the callback before performing bgmChange.
```

I know that i can simply do something like this..

```
$('selector').bgChange({name:'you', function(){
bgmChange();
});
```

but we're talking about hundreds (possibly thousands) of functions lined up.

Is there any way to do this?

Right now the solution that i came up with is something like this.

```
var events = [
function() {$('#canvas').bgChange({img:'resources/bg/afternoon.png',fadeIn: true,autoplay:false, debug:"events1:"});},

function() {$('#canvas').bgChange({img:'resources/bg/nighttime.png',fadeIn: true,autoplay:false, debug:"events2:"});},
function() {$('#canvas').bgChange({img:'resources/bg/afternoon.png',fadeIn: true,autoplay:false, debug:"events3:"});},

function() {$('#canvas').bgChange({img:'resources/bg/afternoon.png',fadeIn: true,autoplay:false, debug:"events4:"});},
function() {$('#canvas').switchTo(events2);}
];
```

and play every function using

```
$('#canvas').play(events);
```

is there any other elegant way to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to continue the chaining after the callback execution as given below

```
$('selector').bgChange({name:'you'},callback).bgmChange()
```

But if you want to give an fixed delay then you can use [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)